# Type Inference for declared instance

Tags: haskell, types

I came up with a nice exercise, but can't make it work.

The idea is to try and express Roman numerals in such a way that the type checker will tell me whether the numeral is valid.

```
    {-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes
               , MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

    data One a b c = One a deriving (Show, Eq)
    data Two a b c = Two (One a b c) (One a b c) deriving (Show, Eq)
    data Three a b c = Three (One a b c) (Two a b c) deriving (Show, Eq)
    data Four a b c = Four (One a b c) (Five a b c) deriving (Show, Eq)
    data Five a b c = Five b deriving (Show, Eq)
    data Six a b c = Six (Five a b c) (One a b c) deriving (Show, Eq)
    data Seven a b c = Seven (Five a b c) (Two a b c) deriving (Show, Eq)
    data Eight a b c = Eight (Five a b c) (Three a b c) deriving (Show, Eq)
    data Nine a b c d e = Nine (One a b c) (One c d e) deriving (Show, Eq)

    data Z = Z deriving (Show, Eq) -- dummy for the last level
    data I = I deriving (Show, Eq)
    data V = V deriving (Show, Eq)
    data X = X deriving (Show, Eq)
    data L = L deriving (Show, Eq)
    data C = C deriving (Show, Eq)
    data D = D deriving (Show, Eq)
    data M = M deriving (Show, Eq)

    i :: One I V X
    i = One I

    v :: Five I V X
    v = Five V

    x :: One X L C
    x = One X

    l :: Five X L C
    l = Five L

    c :: One C D M
    c = One C

    d :: Five C D M
    d = Five D

    m :: One M Z Z
    m = One M

    infixr 4 #

    class RomanJoiner a b c where
      (#) :: a -> b -> c

    instance RomanJoiner (One a b c) (One a b c) (Two a b c) where
      (#) = Two

    instance RomanJoiner (One a b c) (Two a b c) (Three a b c) where
      (#) = Three

    instance RomanJoiner (One a b c) (Five a b c) (Four a b c) where
      (#) = Four

    instance RomanJoiner (Five a b c) (One a b c) (Six a b c) where
      (#) = Six

    instance RomanJoiner (Five a b c) (Two a b c) (Seven a b c) where
      (#) = Seven

    instance RomanJoiner (Five a b c) (Three a b c) (Eight a b c) where
      (#) = Eight

    instance RomanJoiner (One a b c) (One c d e) (Nine a b c d e) where
      (#) = Nine

    main = print $ v # i # i
```

This possibly can be done differently, and the solution is incomplete, but right now I need to understand why it complains that there is no instance for RomanJoiner (One I V X) (One I V X) b0, whereas I think I declared such a joiner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that instances are not chosen based on the
only one that works: one extension `FunctionalDependencies` helps to get some more
type inference. Enabling that, and saying with `| a b -> c` that the type of
`a # b` can be inferred from the types of `a` and `b`. Unfortunately, that's not the only thing you have to do because you'd get the error `Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations`. Using some classes defined in HList (these could be defined anywhere else), the conflicting two instances can be combined into a single one, where the two (or 3 if you count an error) possible results are chosen based on whether some types are equal.

A couple comments about this solution being ugly:

1. you don't have to replicate what's going on at the type level at the value
   level again (`hCond` vs `HCond`) if you had lazier Show instances (like
   `instance Show I where show
   _ = "I"`).
2. with more modern extension `TypeFamilies` many of those intermediate type
   variables  `ba, bb, bc, babc ...` can be eliminated.

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, ScopedTypeVariables, UndecidableInstances, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances #-}
   import Data.HList hiding ((#))
   import Data.HList.TypeEqGeneric1
   import Data.HList.TypeCastGeneric1
   import Unsafe.Coerce

   data One a b c = One a deriving (Show, Eq)
   data Two a b c = Two (One a b c) (One a b c) deriving (Show, Eq)
   data Three a b c = Three (One a b c) (Two a b c) deriving (Show, Eq)
   data Four a b c = Four (One a b c) (Five a b c) deriving (Show, Eq)
   data Five a b c = Five b deriving (Show, Eq)
   data Six a b c = Six (Five a b c) (One a b c) deriving (Show, Eq)
   data Seven a b c = Seven (Five a b c) (Two a b c) deriving (Show, Eq)
   data Eight a b c = Eight (Five a b c) (Three a b c) deriving (Show, Eq)
   data Nine a b c d e = Nine (One a b c) (One c d e) deriving (Show, Eq)

   data Z = Z deriving (Show, Eq) -- dummy for the last level
   data I = I deriving (Show, Eq)
   data V = V deriving (Show, Eq)
   data X = X deriving (Show, Eq)
   data L = L deriving (Show, Eq)
   data C = C deriving (Show, Eq)
   data D = D deriving (Show, Eq)
   data M = M deriving (Show, Eq)

   i :: One I V X
   i = One I

   v :: Five I V X
   v = Five V

   x :: One X L C
   x = One X

   l :: Five X L C
   l = Five L

   c :: One C D M
   c = One C

   d :: Five C D M
   d = Five D

   m :: One M Z Z
   m = One M

   infixr 4 #

   class RomanJoiner a b c | a b -> c where
       (#) :: a -> b -> c


   instance RomanJoiner (One a b c) (Two a b c) (Three a b c) where
       (#) = Three

   instance RomanJoiner (One a b c) (Five a b c) (Four a b c) where
       (#) = Four

   instance RomanJoiner (Five a b c) (One a b c) (Six a b c) where
       (#) = Six

   instance RomanJoiner (Five a b c) (Two a b c) (Seven a b c) where
       (#) = Seven

   instance RomanJoiner (Five a b c) (Three a b c) (Eight a b c) where
       (#) = Eight

   data Error = Error
   instance forall a b c a' b' c' ba bb bc bab babc z bn nine.
      (TypeEq a a' ba,
       TypeEq b b' bb,
       TypeEq c c' bc,
       HAnd ba bb bab,
       HAnd bab bc babc,

       TypeEq c a' bn,
       HCond bn (Nine a b c b' c') Error nine,

       HCond babc (Two a b c) nine  z) =>
           RomanJoiner (One a b c) (One a' b' c') z where
       (#) x y = hCond (undefined :: babc)
                   (Two (uc x :: One a b c) (uc y :: One a b c)) $
                 hCond (undefined :: bn)
                   (Nine (uc x :: One a b c) (uc y :: One c b' c'))
                   Error
           where uc = unsafeCoerce

   main = print $ v # i # i
   {-
   Prints with ghc 762, HList-0.2.3

   *Main> main
   Seven (Five V) (Two (One I) (One I)

   -}
   ```

Comment: Thanks. It is not clear why you needed to treat Two specially, but not the rest of it. Does this mean other numerals will need special treatment of others, too? I'll need to digest the solution.